# Sound Input device (microphone) not working in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, microphone

I have recently updated my laptop OS to Cinnamon 5.6.8

After updating the OS, my laptop's input device ie., microphone is not working

Comment: Share which audio driver and sound server in use. You have different options one of them: run `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -SMA` to examine.

Answer (score -1):

the question"Sound Input device (microphone) not working" asked 8 years ago in ask ubuntu helped me

I did follow the instructions and installed pavucontrol

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

and then noticed that my mic isn't recording any input so I had to reload the

Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA) with the following command

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

then rebooted but still not working so I had to remove all alsa data and renstall it again  with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

since this command deletes cinnamon desktop configuration I had to reinstall it again with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

make sure not to turn off your laptop before finishing the desktop installation because desktop wont run the next time you start your laptop